# excel formula to convert a number between 0-5 as 5 and 5-10 as 10 etc

Tags: excel

I want to write a logic in `excel` that if value in a call is between `0` and `5` then the cell takes value as `5`, if it is between `5` and `10` then the value taken is `10` and so on. How can I do this?

Comment: 5 overlaps, should 5 be 5 or should it be 10?

Comment: Also, do you want to do this in place? or have the result in another column?

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/round-a-number-up-to-nearest-multiple, as a starting point.

Comment: You may try this `=LOOKUP(I2,{0,6},{5,10}) and as @ScottCraner Sir mentioned higher and lower bounds cant be same or overlapped, Also I think what BigBen sir has provided, is simple & easiest !

Comment: thanks. I tried `mlookup`. It seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the int formula
=(INT(C5/5)+1)*5